Flutter run app error final String clearLabel = widget.clearButtonSemanticLabel ?? CupertinoLocalizations.of(context).clearButtonLabel
My app was good until I upgraded my flutter version it show me this error, I changed the project to new one and it still shows the same error.
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/text_field.dart:1129:101: Error: The getter 'clearButtonLabel' isn't defined for the class 'CupertinoLocalizations'.
 - 'CupertinoLocalizations' is from 'package:flutter/src/cupertino/localizations.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/localizations.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'clearButtonLabel'.
    final String clearLabel = widget.clearButtonSemanticLabel ?? CupertinoLocalizations.of(context).clearButtonLabel;
                                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8m 54s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            6.7s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

I tried so many ways like changing project removing packages flutter clean and etc. but I am still getting the same error.

provide code where you use cupertino(localization)

i removed this part of code it still same error
